# Angular Elements with ng-content not working

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I have a custom element created with Angular Elements. That's a simple component with content-projection for some banner.

```
<my-component>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</my-component>
```

I built this app and extracted the main.js outside to be used in another project. In that other Angular app, if I include this script in index.html and use the below

```
<my-component> Hello Angular! </my-component>
```

It works with the script getting loaded fine and index.html rendering it without an issue. But if I include the script in index.html and use the same  in my app.component then the content projection is not working.

Is content projection not supported with elements? do I have to go with slots altogether?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `Hello Angular!` in a `div` element?

Comment: @laudebugs no luck. I tried both wrapping my custom element in a div and also the ng-content inside a div. Either way, projection isn't working. Input/Ouput are working fine.